# /usr/local/cuda/version.txt does not match with /usr/lib/cuda/version

Tags: cuda, version

I realized that the server I am working on has problem with the CUDA versions. WHen I check the CUDA version with `nvidia-smi`, `nvcc --version` and `cat /usr/local/cuda/version.txt` - they all yield version 10.2. However, when I check `/usr/lib/cuda/version.txt`, it yields 9.1. I want to all yield 10.2. Because of this issue, I cannot download some libraries because it says :

> Checking whether the CUDA compiler is NVIDIA using "" did not match
> "nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver":

How can I overcome this conflict of versions?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, you seem to have different versions of CUDA installed on your system:

- `/usr/lib/cuda/version.txt` belongs to the version installed as part of your **Linux distribution**;
- `/usr/local/cuda` has the version of CUDA installed **manually, independently of the distribution** by you or your system administrator.

You likely have these two mixed up w.r.t. lookup paths: Trying to  use the `/usr/local/cuda` version of NVCC with the `/usr/lib/cuda` libraries or vice-versa.

Check:

1. Your environment variables, especially `PATH`, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, and `CUDA_DIR` or `CUDAToolkit_DIR` (the last two are CMake package path search hints).
2. Your linker configuration: `/etc/ld.so.conf` and the `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` directory;

to find the conflicting references.

That being said - you will still have two versions. Any tool which searches common locations may notice this fact. So, whatever you use to "download some libraries" - you may need to figure out what *it* uses to check for versions.